# View doesn't listen to Model Event Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

For some reason I cannot comprehend, events are not being listened to by my View. The model IS changing, but the view doesn't seem to acknowledge these changes. Here's my code.

```
var playerSet = 1;
var bone = function(){
    var app = {};
    app.BoardModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function(){
            return{
                board:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                allDisabled: false,
                p1Score: 0,
                p2Score: 0
            }
        },
        setSlot: function(slot, ct){
            var b = this.get("board");
            b[slot] = ct;
            this.set("board", b);
            console.log("CHANGED");
        }
    });
    app.Board = new app.BoardModel;
    app.BoardView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#ttt-board"),
        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(app.Board, "change", this.renderBoard);
        },
        renderBoard: function(){
            console.log("HELLO THERE");
        }
    });
    var tictac = new app.BoardView;
    app.Board.setSlot(0,1);
};
bone();
```

When I fire `setSlot`, the model does change as the console outputs `CHANGED`, however I never see the renderBoard function being called.

This is probably incredibly simple, but it eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only changing the internal components of the array object, not the attribute on your model. Even though you are manually calling `set` on the model, this is not an actual change and the `set` logic only triggers a change event if the equality check between the old and new values fails (which in your case it doesn't).

Since you are calling a custom function anyways, why not just use a custom event?

```
setSlot: function(slot, ct){
  this.get("board")[slot] = ct;
  this.trigger("custom:change:board", slot, ct);
}
```

Now listen for the custom event (or both) instead of just `change`.

```
initialize: function(){
  this.listenTo(app.Board, "change custom:change:board", this.renderBoard);
}
```

Comment: ok, should calling `this.trigger("change")` do the trick? Or another thing altogether?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely trigger change directly. `this.trigger('change', this, options);` I tend to avoid doing so though because it is common for there to be multiple handlers that are listening for the `change` event and you may be surprised when event handlers do wacky things because the state that `set` manages under the hood is not setup as expected when the `change` event is manually triggered.

Comment: I am quite pleased with the custom event solution. `this.trigger("change")` solves my problem, but I think your solution is a lot more elegant.